# discord.py AttributeError: 'Embed' object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I'm trying to resend an embed from a message ID, this is my code

```
@commands.command()
async def test(self, ctx, messageID: int):
    channel = self.client.get_channel(740951313482907748)
    
    message = await channel.fetch_message(messageID)
    embed = message.embeds[0]
    embed = discord.Embed.from_dict(embed)
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Whenever I run it, this error appears:

```
Ignoring exception in command take:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\kwiecinski\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 83, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\kwiecinski\Desktop\test_bot\cogs\channels.py", line 61, in take
    embed = discord.Embed.from_dict(embedfrommessage)
  File "C:\Users\kwiecinski\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\embeds.py", line 147, in from_dict
    self.title = data.get('title', EmptyEmbed)
AttributeError: 'Embed' object has no attribute 'get'
```

```
print(type(embed))
>>> <class 'discord.embeds.Embed'>
```

How can I get rid of that error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you try to get an embed from an embed. Thus this line (which causes the error) should be removed: `embed = discord.Embed.from_dict(embed)`.

The reason why the error occurs. Is that the [embed object](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=embed#discord.Embed) doesnt have an attribute 'get'. Which can be easily checked when looking at the documentation of the [embed object](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=embed#discord.Embed), there is simply no attribute called "get".

```
@commands.command()
async def test(self, ctx, messageID: int):
    channel = self.client.get_channel(740951313482907748)

    message = await channel.fetch_message(messageID)
    embed = message.embeds[0] # this line returns an embed
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to create an embed from already existing embed.
Remove

```
embed = discord.Embed.from_dict(embed)
```

and you will be fine